# I am having troubling pulling an element from my array and comparing it in my condition

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, indexing, slice

```
howManyNames = (float(input("Enter how many student names do you want to enter? ")))
studentNames = []
ages = []
averageAge = 0
counter = 0

while (counter < int(howManyNames)):
    studentNames.append(input("Enter student names. "))
    ages.append(float(input("Enter that persons age. ")))
    counter += 1
    averageAge = sum(ages) / float(howManyNames)

while (ages[:] < int(averageAge)): ## crashes because its comparing a list < int  
    print ("Your age is below the average age.", ages)
    if ages > averageAge:
        print ("Your age is above the average age.", ages)
        break
```

I get the error message 
TypeError: unorderable types: list() < int()
I even tried a slices to see if that worked.....

Comment: What are you trying to do? Obviously you cant compare apples to oranges or lists to ints.

Comment: i was trying to pull my elements stored in ages..... and compare those elements to my int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you meant, no?

Evaluate if age in the `ages` variable is smaller or bigger than the average.

```
for age in ages:
   if age < int(averageAge):
      print ("Your age is below the average age.", age)
   else:
      print ("Your age is above the average age.", age)
```

a `while` loop will continue to run until the condition is not true anymore.

```
while condition is true:
       #do something
```

What you were saying didn't make any sense. You said `while [1, 2, 3] < 4:` That is exactly like saying `while speed < car` you weren't comparing anything valid. Since it is a list you need to iterate (using the for loop) over every object then compare it to you average. That is a valid comparison. I hope this explains the problem

Comment: thanks man definitely helped out, i will had the feel of where i needed to go, but couldn't see. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You were trying to compare the entire list of ages against the average age, rather than comparing each individual element/age in the list like jramirez has demonstrated you should do.